# Why table gets distracted in the following scenario?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having a from in which table is there.
In table there are 3 columns.
I want to `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` the textbox in third column depending on enabling and disabling of checkbox.
When i enable the check box text box fadeIn is done but the table column width gets changed.
So how to overcome this issue.
http://jsfiddle.net/7gbNK/60/

Code is as follows:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
     <table width="50%" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="1" border="1">
         <tr>
             <td width="5%" align="center"><input name="chk_surname" id="chk_surname" type="checkbox" onclick="enable(this.id,'surname','td_surname')"></td>
             <td width="10%" align="center">Surname</td>
             <td width="35%" class="td_surname" style="display:none;" align="center"><input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" /></td>
         </tr>
     </table>
</form>
```

Javascript Code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function enable(id,name,className)
    {
        $(document).on('change','#'+id, function() 
        {
            var checked = $(this).is(":checked");

            var index = $(this).parent().index();

            if(checked) {
                $('.'+className).fadeIn(100);
            }
            else {
                $('.'+className).fadeOut(100);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of distracted table]

Comment: Your table cell is `display: none`, therefore it's not rendered. Hide the content of the cell instead, not the cell itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FadeIn and FadeOut the `input` box instead of the `td`.

Try this:

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
     <table width="50%" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="1" border="1">
         <tr>
             <td width="10%" align="center"><input name="chk_surname" id="chk_surname" type="checkbox" onclick="enable(this.id,'surname','td_surname')"></td>
             <td width="20%" align="center">Surname</td>
             <td width="70%" class="td_surname" align="center"><input style="display:none;" type="text" name="surname" id="surname" /></td>
         </tr>
     </table>
</form>
```

JS:

```
function enable(id,name,className)
{
        //Commented lines below are not required. These are present in your code
        //$(document).on('change','#'+id, function() 
        //{
            var el = '#'+id;
            var checked = $(el).is(":checked");

            var index = $(el).parent().index();

            if(checked) {
                $('#'+name).fadeIn(100);
            }
            else {
                $('#'+name).fadeOut(100);
            }
        //});
    }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/W2wQF/

Reason why the original code is behaving that way is because when the third column is removed from display then the remaining two columns expand to fill its space. In the fixed code, third column is never removed (only its contents are removed/displayed).